# Is there a way to loop and make a plot in Altair?

Tags: python, numpy, altair

I am trying to replicate this matplotlib plot in Altair. What would be the best way to do it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
N = 10
a = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=(N))
b = np.random.normal(1, 0.5, size=(N))
x_seq = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)

for i in range(N):
  plt.plot(x_seq, a[i] + b[i] * x_seq, "k-", alpha=0.3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib has a low level plotting interface that promotes loops operating on arrays (as in your example) whereas packages such as Altair and Seaborn have high level interfaces that work with dataframes and their column names.

So instead of your for loop, you would could do something like this in Altair:

```
import altair as alt


dfx = pd.DataFrame([a[i] + b[i] * x_seq for i in range(N)]).T
dfx['x'] = x_seq
dfx = dfx.melt(id_vars='x', var_name='line_group', value_name='y')

alt.Chart(dfx).mark_line().encode(
    x='x', 
    y='y',
    color='line_group:N') # N is to explicitly indicate a nominal variable
```

[image]

[You can read more about the melting step and why long data is perferred in the docs.](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data)

Comment: Thanks so much. Let's say N=100. The resulting dataframe will be huge. Is there a way to do it without building the entire dataframe in advance?

Comment: @arjan-hada You might be able to create individual smaller dataframes (or use the [sequence generator](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#sequence-generator) but not much difference) and then plot one line at a time as a new plot that you append to a list and then use `alt.layer` on all the items in the list.